# Removing last element of each sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have the following list:

```
{{1, 4}, {1, 3, 8}, {7, 12}, {2, 4, 9, 12}, {5, 7, 18, 19, 22}, {3, 5}}
```

How can I obtain a list in which each last element of the sublists is removed:

```
{{1}, {1, 3}, {7}, {2, 4, 9}, {5, 7, 18, 19}, {3}}
```

Comment: Try `Drop[list, 0, -1]`. `0` can also be `None`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Most

You are after [`Most`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Most.html), [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)ped over the list. Notice that `f/@l` is just a short form for `Map[f,l]`.

```
Most /@ {{1, 4}, {1, 3, 8}, {7, 12}, {2, 4, 9, 12}, {5, 7, 18,
    19, 22}, {3, 5}}
(* {{1}, {1, 3}, {7}, {2, 4, 9}, {5, 7, 18, 19}, {3}} *)
```

### Part

You can use also [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) (`[[ ]]`).

```
Part[
 {{1, 4}, {1, 3, 8}, {7, 12}, {2, 4, 9, 12}, {5, 7, 18, 19, 22}, {3, 
   5}}
 , All
 , 1 ;; -2
 ]
```

or

```
{{1, 4}, {1, 3, 8}, {7, 12}, {2, 4, 9, 12}, {5, 7, 18, 19, 22}, {3, 
   5}}[[All, 1 ;; -2]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions.

Comment: What is the justification for voting to close this question and then, in  effect, posting a duplicate as an answer?

Comment: @tomd I didn't vote that it was a duplicate, I voted that it was *"easily found in the documentation"*. But you are correct, I was focused on giving the OP a quick answer, I should have searched for duplicates and I didn't. My wrong.  Good thing that Anton Antonov, Bob Hanlon, MarcoB, and Mr.Wizard identified it correctly.